# How to implement voiceover for the pages with WKWebview and UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

How to implement voiceover for the pages with WKWebview and UIWebview. 
I have tried it both type of views but no Luck.

i have webview inside a normal view. I have set the normal view accessibility to false and added the same for webeview.

Can any one help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the view not-accessible, as you have, but leave the web view unchanged. If this doesn't work, please update your question with more details, including the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me now. I was trying to change the accessibility settings for Webview. Leaving it as is is the fix. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @girishkumareduru No problem! If the answer solved your problem, please mark it "accepted."